# HLS adaptive streaming in android changes streams only after 10 secs?

Tags: video-streaming, android-mediaplayer, http-live-streaming, android-videoview, exoplayer

I have developed a small app that can record and play small videos (upto 10 secs). The app captures video at 6 Mbps. To ensure faster video playback, I'm trying to implement HLS (http live streaming). But I have noticed that the app always picks up the stream with lowest bitrate first and only switches to the best available stream (based on network bandwidth) only after 10 secs.

I have tested different media players like android media player, [exoplayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) etc., but the behaviour is consistent. The video changes streams only after exactly 10 seconds. Is this the default implementation of hls in android? or Am I missing something?
The m3u8 I used to test is http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8

```
        localUrl = "http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8";
        vidView.setVideoPath(localUrl);
        Log.i("GenericRequest", "VideoUrl " + localUrl);
        vidView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
             vidView.start();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 6):

If you look at the contents of the playlists listed in `bipbopall.m3u8`, you'll see that the segment duration is 10 seconds. This probably explains why you are seeing the switch after 10 seconds.

The player will download the first playlist listed in `bipbopall.m3u8`, which in this instance is the stream with the lowest bitrate, and starts playing the first segment. It subsequently calculates that there is additional bandwidth available so switches to a stream with a higher bitrate.

If the segment duration were different, you'd likely see the switch occur at a different time.